# Node v5.2.0 and fs-extra

Tags: node.js, fs

For some reason, Node v5.2.0 doesn't like the `fs-extra` `inflight` dependency. However, if I don't install `fs-extra`, my project builds just fine.

See:

- [Build #3](https://travis-ci.org/eggers/generator-ts-module/builds/96212150) Node 5.2.0 succeeds other versions of node fail.
- [Build #4](https://travis-ci.org/eggers/generator-ts-module/builds/96212814) 5.2.0 fails, others succeed.

What would be the best ways of getting the build to work with all environments?

Comment: fs-extra author here. Looked at your test failures. Doesn't look like anything to do with fs-extra, but you're missing the fs-extra dependency in your devDependencies: https://github.com/eggers/generator-ts-module/blob/ac326dd1602ef68a93f73adb43005ce12f0e8687/package.json But it looks like you've solved this in `master` now.

Comment: @JPRichardson I didn't solve it, I just removed the node stable environment.